# javascript to approve Microsoft flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, flow

I have created several Approval flow.
These flows send an approval email to approver and  they work fine. 
Now I want to create a page (classic sharepoint) with all items of all flows to approve (something like the execution list in microsoft flow page)

[image]

and directly in this list approve or reject items?

The Approve Link ore Reject in the mail is something like this:

```
https://flow.microsoft.com/manage/environments/[TENANT GUID]/approvals/received/[FLOW GUID]/requests/[ITEM GUID]?respose=

'Approve' OR 'Reject'


 &utm_source=approvals_univ&utm_medium=email&environment=[TENANT GUID]&loginTenant=[TENANT GUID]
```

There is a way to get the Flow Item Guid and create a javascript function to execute?

Thanks to everybody
Marco